# Using Style.Triggers without overriding default style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm working with *MahApps.Metro* toolkit for WPF and can't figure out how to create Button within *MetroWindow.RightWindowCommand* with custom *Button.Style* tag with some triggers inside it, and **do not override** fancy, default style provided by toolkit.

Solution should be like :

```
<Metro:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
        <Metro:WindowCommands>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Turn off" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ClosedPerm}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Turn on" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Metro:WindowCommands>
    </Metro:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

However BasedOn="{**StaticResource {x:Type Button}**}" gives button default metro button look, instead of specific look inside Metro:WindowCommands.

Any ideas how to apply default style without copying huge ammount of code from source files?